Replace relay with MOSFET in vehicle application
I need to convert a signal indicating whether my vehicle's engine is running. Thus, the environment is about 12V DC, the “about” in anticipation of low battery, or running dynamo.
The car provides me with an input signal, which is either connected to ground when the engine is running, providing a current sink for at most 250mA according to the manufacturer's documentation, or it is floating when the engine stops.
The output signal I need should be “about” +12V if the engine is running (input is pulled low) or 0V otherwise. This signal controls a battery charger for a secondary battery, which I assume not to draw more than 100mA on that signal line.
Obviously, the vehicle manufacturer provides the signal to drive a relay. Which would be the most simple approach, I guess.
I'd like to do this with transistors, and I think that a variation of a CMOS inverter would suffice. I came up with the following diagram.
Questions:

Am I on the right track?  Can this be improved?
I'm a bit lost with choosing the concrete MOSFETs — I'd prefer THT mounting, I'm to clumsy for anything smaller…
and I have just guessed the 10kΩ for the pull-up resistor, advice on the dimension is welcome…



As most charging systems have a voltage of >13.4V when the engine is running I would control using that. One method we used was to drive a relay based on the charge warning light feed from the alternator - as this ws a voltage balance it would only close the relay when the alternator was running to produce sufficient charge.

"I assume not to draw more than 100mA on that signal line" - why do you assume that? What information do you have about that charger?

Yes, you are on the right track, add a fuse in the 12 V path.

@SolarMike: Checking for 13.4V would require me to measure voltage.  Probably doable, but described input signal is available and maybe more easily usable.

@Finbarr: I was not able to find current ratings for the signal line in the accompanying documentation. The charger draws its power via different cables, specified to 6mm² cross-section and fused at 40A.  The documentation specifies neither cable cross-section nor fuse for the signal I need to provide.  The device generates a different signal at 12V that is specified to allow loads up to 100mA.  Hope.

what is the purpose of the N channel MOSFET?


Yes, you're on the right track.

Something in a TO-220 package fated for 2 x the circuit conditions.  For a 12 V circuit, a 25 V (or higher) FET Vds.  For a 1 A circuit, a 2 A (or more) Id.  A Car is a high vibration environment; the FETs won't need heatsinks, but the will need to be bolted down.

The 10K value is fine.  At 1 K you need to increase the size of the resistor because of heat.  At 100 K the circuit impedance is so high that it will be more susceptible to radiated noise.


Based on my read of your description, there is no need for the n-channel FET. <reference designators - !>  It can be replaced with a simple pull-down resistor.  Something in the 1.5 K to 4.7 K range should work.
Note that this assumes that the charger input does not require sinking more than 10 mA out of its input to hold it in the OFF state.
Also - Vehicles are a terrible electrical environment.  In an application like yours, I prefer bipolar transistors.  Something slow, fat, reliable, and cheap like a PNP TIP30 or TIP32.  This would require adding a current limiting resistor in series with the base.  1 K, 1/2 W should work well.
Update:
Another possible issue is that, depending on the exact part numbers for the FETs, as the voltage on the two gates transitions from +12 V to GND it passes through a voltage range where both FETs are "on".  This is called cross-conduction, and the current spike could be many amps if the transistors are big enough.  The original bipolar 555 was famous for this.

I've found this design in “The Art of Electronics” (this book is a long way beyond my capabilities, tbh), but it seems to be well-known otherwise as well.  As I understand, the low output impedance would give more reliable switching.  You think of that in your 2nd paragraph, right?  Ok, I'll keep "traditional" transistors as plan B in the back of my head.  Relay is plan C.

“as the voltage on the two gates transitions from +12 V to GND it passes through a voltage range where both FETs are "on".” — Ok, this kills it for me.  I'm not prepared to risk a costly repair of my car.  I'm going to build this, but only as an experiment.  My car will see a relay.

For a practical solution, I'd just use a relay.  As a design exercise, lets go with transistors!
One difference between a solid state solution vs an electromechanical solution is the response time.  Another is the need for low voltage and high voltage tolerances. Your circuit will work in concept.  In practice it will have problems unless the design can address these.
Your FETs (or bipolars) will respond far more quickly than a relay will.  There are use cases, primarily when turning on or battery disconnect, that also need to be considered.
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva681a/snva681a.pdf?ts=1730981095184
See the above link for information about both cases.  The TI document gives transient min and max voltage for the "12V'  A solution will need to withstand voltages between 3V and 78V (for a 12V system) without either failing or giving a false 'ON' indication.
I've worked on projects where circuits needed to operate in this environment.  The solutions aren't simple, and for a one of design, I'd look at 12V automotive relay along with some de-bounce in the circuit past this to handle the false positive transients.

I'll do as you suggest and go for relay.  Technically, AnalogKid has
answered my question, so i've chosen that.  Sorry I cannot choose both.

All good. The reason to ask a question here is to learn about how to solve your problem and also to decide how you choose to move forward in solving your problem.  It's good that you have done both here.
